npx : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. Error
npx : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

npx create-react-app .

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess




I encountered this error, Need to fix error

Have you tried following that link? You will find the exact steps what to do ...

This question is similar to: PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system.". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This error occurs because PowerShell has restricted script execution for security reasons.
Steps to Fix:

Open PowerShell as Administrator

Check Current Execution Policy
Get-ExecutionPolicy
If it shows Restricted, you need to change it.

Set Execution Policy to Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Verify the Change: run this cmd
enter code here

Retry the npx Command
npx create-react-app .



here's. I solve these problem using easy and quick steps

Type Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser

Type RemoteSigned

Then Yes as Y type


then solved the error

What is the purpose of this question, which you answered by yourself within minutes? It's not a new issue, because the same question has been answered multiple times here on SO already ...
